# ExtJS 3 Complete Application Example

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am looking for as complete an example of an ExtJS 3 application such as the [Feed Viewer Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html), only readily downloadable and deployable on a local development server.

The application should demonstrate at the least breaking up an application into multiple javascript source files and communicating with a server.

Does anybody know of any such examples? I am able to find stuff for ExtJS 2 but not a whole lot of stuff for ExtJS 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://app.extjsinaction.com/app.zip

This is [an example App](http://extjsinaction.com/the-application) from [Jay Garcia's](http://tdg-i.com/) book ExtJS in Action (which I recommend very much)